# Hangman code won't detect correct guesses

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Edit: Solved. Thank you, bruno desthuilliers!

I'm doing a Hangman game for a school assignment, and I've run into an error. My program will not correctly identify when correct guesses are made, and instead will say every guess is incorrect.

I'll break down the main loop of my program. All the code before and after is introductory and concluding dialogue that works as intended. The problem is in guessing the word.

This part of my code works fine - this is handling different types of invalid inputs.

```
while "_" in placeholder:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    if not guess.isalpha():
        print("Please enter a letter.")
    elif not len(guess) == 1:
        print("Please enter one letter only.")  
    elif guess in previous_guesses:
        print("You have already guessed that letter. Please guess a letter")
```

Here's the problematic part. This is where the program checks if the guessed letter is in the word. word_letters is simply a list of letters in the word - formed by word.split()

```
elif guess in word_letters: 
    print("'" + guess + "'" + " is in the word. Good guess!")
    previous_guesses.append(guess)
    index = word_letters.index(guess)
    for index, letter in enumerate(word_letters):
        if letter == guess:
            placeholder[index] = guess
```

Again, this part down here works fine. Should only happen when the guess is wrong, but it happens even if the guess was right.

```
else:
    print("'" + guess + "'" + " is not in the word. Try again.")
    previous_guesses.append(guess)
    stage += 1
    Hangman.draw(stage)
```

I don't really understand why this doesn't work properly. I created a test block which models EXACTLY what happens in my main program, and it works properly.

```
placeholder = ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
word_letters = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
guess = input("guess ")
if guess in word_letters:
  print("It works")
  index = word_letters.index(guess)
  for index, letter in enumerate(word_letters):
    if letter == guess:
      placeholder[index] = guess
  print(placeholder)    
else:
  print("It didn't work")
```

Can anyone explain to me what exactly the problem with my main program is?

Comment: Beware that for loops also have else blocks which run I think when the for loop either fails or never runs.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. Your code works fine. If you print the placeholder it works the same as your test? Could you people provide more information what the incorrect test output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "word_letters is simply a list of letters in the word - formed by word.split()"

Then look no further - `word_letters` is not what you think it is:

```
>>> word = "hello"
>>> word_letters = word.split()
>>> word_letters
['hello']
>>> "h" in word_letters
False
```

`str.split(sep=None)` will actually split the string on `sep`, which defaults to any "whitespace" character:

```
>>> "hello word".split()
['hello', 'word']
>>> "hello\nword".split()
['hello', 'word']
>>> "hello\tword".split()
['hello', 'word']
```

To make a `list` of a string's characters, you'd have to use `list(yourstring)`, ie:

```
>>> word_letters = list(word)
>>> word_letters
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> "h" in word_letters
True
```

BUT this is not even necessary here since string are sequences and support containment test already:

```
>>> word
'hello'
>>> 'h' in word
True
```

and the `index` method too:

```
>>> "hello".index("h")
0
>>> "hello".index("o")
4
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! word_letters exists only because I wasn't sure about how enumerate() behaved when you passed a string into the arguments.

Comment: @James the Python shell is a very handy tool to test things - like "how enumerate() behaves when passed a string" ;)

Comment: ps : if it solves your problem then feel free to accept the answer (and eventually upvote it too)